# Angular 4 - Testing a http.get call that is in my component and is not in an external service

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm awful with testing and I am sure the answer here is really easy but I have a bit of a mental block, so thanks to anyone who can help. In my component I load a static JSON file like such, notice I don't use a service, I call directly the http object:

```
public crispList: any;

public ngOnInit() {
  this.crispList = this.http.get('path/to/crisp-flavors.json').map((res: any) => {
        const respJson = res.json();
        return respJson.walkers.crisps;
      });
  }
}
```

I want to test that the crispList is populated in my test file, I wrote the following in my test file, but I am unsure how I call/mock the this.http.get call as I wish to a) test that the call is made and b) the property/variable crispList has the value that I mock, here's my test code:

```
describe('CrispFlavourComponent', () => {
  let backend: MockBackend = null;
  let componentFixture: any;
  const mockResponse = {
    walkers: {
      crisps: [
          {
            name: 'Salt & Vinegar',
          }, {
            name: 'Cheese & Onion',
          }

        ]
      }
    }
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          {path: '**', component: DummyComponent}
        ]),
        TranslateI18NextTestingModule.forRoot()],
      declarations: [
        DummyComponent, CrispFlavorComponent
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backendInstance: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
            return new Http(backendInstance, defaultOptions);
          },
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        }]
    });

    TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
      componentFixture = TestBed.createComponent(CrispFlavourComponent);
    });

  }));u

  beforeEach(inject([MockBackend], (mockBackend: MockBackend) => {

    backend = mockBackend;
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
      const options = new ResponseOptions({
        status: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
      });
      return connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));
    });

    it('should load the list of Crisp Flavors', () => {
    const instance = componentFixture.componentInstance;
    instance.ngOnInit();
    // this.http.get('path/to/crisp-flavors.json').subscribe((res) => {
    // expect("something") or expect instance.crispList is the mocked value
    // })
  });
```

Notice the part that is commented out, here I want to make the http call or mock the call to test the mocked result. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What’s the stack trace error?

Comment: As the expect is commented out all is file, should I remove the comment lines for the this.http.get I obviously get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` as this.http isn't mocked, that is the part I am not sure how to mock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are returning a success. 
In this case, you should, as you did, call your function `ngOnInit`. 
But first, you should create spies on your methods.

Start by setting up your spies:

```js
const instance = componentFixture.componentInstance;
// Array notation for I don't know if your http is private
spyOn(instance['http'], 'get').and.callThrough();
instance.ngOnInit();
```

Now, all you need to do is test if your call has been made, and if the answer if correct :

```js
expect(instance['http']['get']).toHaveBeenCalledWith('path/to/crisp-flavors.json');
expect(instance.crispList).toEqual(mockResponse.walkers.crisps);
```

After that, remember to mock an error and test what your component does in this case!

Comment: That's great but I am using mocha rather than Jasmin so I have to call the spyOn from sinon or somewhere else, I shall see what I can do but your advice is great

Comment: Well do as you please, but to test an endpoint you need to test the URL, the method, and if you process the response, test if the response has the good format. and I gave you all three there

Comment: That is true but If I tried to test the end result, don't I need to subscribe as the instance.crispList test fails, the value of `instance.crispList` is `expected { Object (_isScalar, observers, ...) } to equal { Object ( ...) }`

Comment: Damn sorry I thought you were already subscribing ! Sure, subscribe to your crisplist, and put your expects into n the success of the subscribe, my bad !